# Percentage in SQL using query

Tags: sql, oracle, percentage

This is my table and i want to find the percentage of those who have vaccination_date1 as not null.
My guess is ,it would look like

```
SELECT COUNT(SSRN) FROM CITIZEN WHERE VACCINATION_DATE1 IS NOT NULL/COUNT(SSRN) FROM CITIZEN
```

but i am not sure,any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE CITIZEN(
fname varchar(60) not null,
lname varchar(60) not null,
citizen_id varchar(10) not null,
ssrn number(20) primary key,
birthday date not null,
age number(3),
adress varchar(60) not null,
adr_num number(15) not null,
postal_code number(15)not null,
town varchar(60),
state varchar(60),
country varchar(60)not null,
vaccine varchar(15),
vaccination_date1 char(1),
vaccination_date2 char(1),
constraint citizen_country_fk foreign key (country) references country(country_name),
constraint citizen_vaccine_fk foreign key (vaccine) references vaccine(vaccine_id)
);
```

Comment: Well, did you try running it, and see what the results are?

Comment: i would guess it would return a number but i got an error saying "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Obviously, the code exactly as you have it is not valid SQL. If you look at it - it is an arithmetic expression (a division), where the two numbers are returned by `SELECT` statements. Those statements are correct, but then you use them as inputs to your division. If you want to run this as a SQL statement, you will need to select it from `dual`, or something like that. But that's not the most efficient approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when vaccination_date1 is not null then 1.0 else 0 end) 
from citizen;
```

If you want a value between 0 and 100:

```
select avg(case when vaccination_date1 is not null then 100.0 else 0 end) 
from citizen;
```

And if you want this formatted as a string with `%`:

```
select to_number(avg(case when vaccination_date1 is not null then 100.0 else 0 end), 'FM990.00') || '%'
from citizen;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most efficient way is to do the whole computation in a single query. Something like this:

```
select count(case when vaccination_date1 is not null then 1 end) / count(*)
from .....
```

This will return a number like 0.45, for example; left to you to display it as a percentage (45%), and to give the column a reasonable alias.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any CASE expression, as `count` only counts non-null values. Therefore you can just use:

```
select count(*) as citizen_count
     , count(vaccination_date1) as vaccinated
     , round(100 * count(vaccination_date1)/count(*)) as percent_vaccinated
from   citizen;

CITIZEN_COUNT VACCINATED PERCENT_VACCINATED
------------- ---------- ------------------
          107         35                 33
```